# Thymeleaf - How to iterate list of objects in multiple columns of html with Bootstrap 4.5.0+

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following in Thymeleaf template:

```
<div class="row col-md-12">
        <div th:each="item : ${itemList}">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="card custom-card"
                    style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${'item Id - ' + item.id}">Id</h5>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${item.itemname}">Name</p>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${item.itemdescription}">Desc</p>
                        <a th:href="@{'/createforItemId/' + ${item.id}}"
                            class="stretched-link btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2"><i
                            class="fas fa-rocket mr-2"></i> Start New Discussion</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to iterate the itemList in such a way that `each row in my html should have 4 cards in 4 columns (12/3)`.

But currently I am getting only one "Single" column (huge) stacked with my list of objects.

**What I am missing here?**

I am open for any alternative solution too. Please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152140/problem-with-creating-multiple-bootstrap-rows-dynamically-with-thymeleaf-in-orde

Answer (score 2):

ODD but I got a workaround and is pretty much what I wanted. The following did the trick for me (notice the `table` without `<td></td>`):

```
<table style="width: 100%">
        <tr th:each="item : ${itemList}">
            <div class="card custom-card text-center mr-2 mt-2 ml-2 mb-2"
                    style="width: 15rem; display: inline-block">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" th:text="${'item Id - ' + item.id}">Id</h5>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${item.itemname}">Name</p>
                        <p class="card-text" th:text="${item.itemdescription}">Desc</p>
                        <a th:href="@{'/createforItemId/' + ${item.id}}"
                            class="stretched-link btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2"><i
                            class="fas fa-rocket mr-2"></i> Start New Discussion</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I am getting nice looking 4 columns with 4 cards with this css to add rounded borders for the boxes/cards:

```
.custom-card {
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

However, I am still waiting for some expert's suggestion here as the solution I came up with looks more like a patch work instead of a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include the `th:each` one level up to create 4 cards in a 12 slot row by `col-xl-3`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3" th:each="item : ${itemList}">

            <div class="card">
                <!-- other stuff -->
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

It is similar to this [later posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152140/problem-with-creating-multiple-bootstrap-rows-dynamically-with-thymeleaf-in-orde) question that uses 3 cards instead of 4.

A solution like you have that uses a `<div>` in the `<tr>` will have your IDE complain that `<div>` is not a valid element in that location.

Note that you may still need to constrain the height of the card if they are not of the same size.