# Problem with creating multiple Bootstrap rows dynamically with Thymeleaf in order to display all the products from the database to my web app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm trying to do an Amazon Clone web app, with Java, Spring and Thymeleaf. I have multiple products in my database, and i want to show then in the page, like this (in this case i have 3 products in my database):

[image]

I use thymeleaf th:each in order to iterate through the products from the database. But there is a problem when i try to put multiple rows. I use bootstrap rows and cols in order to have 3 products per row. When there are more than 3 products to display, I need to dynamically add another row with thymeleaf, and there comes the problem. This is all the essential code:

This is the html:

```
           <div class="row" th:each="row : ${rows}">
                <div class="col-xl-4" th:each="product : ${products}">
                    <div class="product-container">
                        <div class="product">
                            <p th:text="${product.getTitle()}"></p>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <small>$</small>
                                <strong th:text="${product.getPrice()}"></strong>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mb-2">
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            </div>
                            <img th:src="${product.getImageUrl()}">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <button>Add To Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HomeController {

    private final ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView showHome(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        modelAndView.addObject("products", productService.getAllProducts());
        modelAndView.addObject("rows", productService.getRows());

        System.out.println(productService.getRows().size());

        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

And this is the Product Service:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ProductService {

    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    public List<ProductDto> getAllProducts(){
        List<ProductEntity> productsEntity = productRepository.findAll();
        List<ProductDto> productsDto = new ArrayList<>();

        for (ProductEntity product :
                productsEntity) {
            productsDto.add(ProductMapper.entityToDto(product));
        }

        return productsDto;
    }

    public List<Integer> getRows() {
        List<ProductEntity> productEntities = productRepository.findAll();
        List<Integer> rows = new ArrayList<>();

        int rowCount = productEntities.size() / 4;

        for (int i = 0; i <= rowCount; i++)
            rows.add(i);

        return rows;
    }
}
```

This is what happens if I add one more product to the database, so there are 4 products in total:

[image]

When I have 4 products, it should add another row, and the 4-th product should be displayed on that row. My whole logic was this: calculate with getRows() from ProductService how many rows should be added, taken into consideration the number of products in the database, then just iterate through the products. But here is the problem I think. For each row, I display every product in database. I need a way to display only the first 3 products in the first row, then the next 3 products for the second row, etc. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Bootstrap you dont need to deal with all this. to Display 3 products in each line, you just have to do something like this.

```
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xl-4" th:each="product : ${products}">
                    <div class="product-container">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

col classes indicate the number of columns you’d like to use out of the possible 12 per row. So, if you want three equal-width columns across, you can use .col-4.